# Project Server 2007 SP2 to SP3

Tags: project-server, service-pack, patching, project2007

We are currently on Project Server 2007 SP2 (including CUs through August 2009.) Our environment is on one server (sharepoint and DBs.) We also connect using MS Project Pro 2007. I'd like to apply SP3.

1. What order do I need to apply these, and do they all need to go on the server? (and please let me know if something is not needed/redundant in this list):

   - Office and sharepoint SP3
   - Project pro 2007 SP3
   - Project Server 2007 SP3
   - Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 SP3
2. Do I need to keep Project Pro 07 client in sync and load Office 2007 SP3? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

two things.
for the project server upgrade, you should apply the patch

- install the Windows SharePoint service 3.0 SP1
- Install the Project Server 2007 SP3
- Install the Language packs SP3 (if any)
  Now you need to patch your Porject client office on the pc. Client upgrade is not impacted by the server upgrade.

Further go through the below technet, it is for SP1 but valid for SP3.
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197653(v=office.12).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197653%28v=office.12%29.aspx)